# How to create instance of a generic type passed to the service method?

Tags: c#, generics, types, casting

I am confused a bit about creating instance of generic object. I belive, that it supposed to be casted(somehow). In my code I am calling a service generic method:

`jockey = await _scrapDataService.ScrapSingleJockeyPlAsync<LoadedJockey>(id, jobType);`

And in my service method I want to achieve this, but I am not sure how to do it:

```
public Task<T> ScrapGenericObject<T>(int id, string jobType)
        {
            var someObject = new T();
            return someObject;
        }
```

Comment: What do you plan to do with `id` and `jobType`? Do you need to pass those to `T` somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the [`new` constraint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new-constraint)

> The new constraint specifies that any type argument in a generic class
>   declaration must have a public parameterless constructor. To use the
>   new constraint, the type cannot be abstract.

```
public Task<T> ScrapGenericObject<T>(int id, string jobType) where T : new()
{
    var someObject = new T();
    return someObject;
}
```

If you need to pass in any constructors you will have to use a different approach [Activator.CreateInstance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.activator.createinstance?view=netframework-4.8)

> Creates an instance of the specified type using the constructor that
>   best matches the specified parameters.

```
 return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), new object[] { param1, param2 });
```

Comment: You are right, I will have to walk it around, if I want to use properties of the object.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler will only allow this if you have a *generic type constraint* that tells the compiler that your type has a public parameterless constructor.

You achieve this using the `new()` constraint:

```
public Task<T> ScrapGenericObject<T>(int id, string jobType) where T: new()
```

Then the compiler knows that whatever type you pass in can be constructed via `new T()`.